# How can I load test my website on Azure?

Tags: azure

I need to measure how many concurrent users my current azure subscription will accept, to determine my cost per user. How can I do this?

Comment: When you say "current azure subscription" what do you mean? Are you talking about a deployed web role/website?

Comment: Yes. I'm using a web role deployed to a small compute instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a big area within capacity planning of a product/solution, but effectively you need to script up a user scenario, say using a tool like `JMeter` or VS2012 Ultimate has a similar feature, then fire-off lots of requests to your site an monitor the results.

Visual Studio can deploy your Azure project using a profiling mode, which is great for detecting the bottlenecks in your code for optimisation. But if you just want to see how many requests per/role before it breaks something like JMeter should work.

There are also lots of products out there on offer, like http://loader.io/ which is great for not worrying about bandwidth issues, scripting, etc... and it should just work.

If you do role your own manual load testing scripts, please be careful to avoid false negatives or false positives, by this I mean that if you internet connection is slow and you send out millions of requests, the bandwidth of your internet may cause your site to appear VERY slow, when in-fact its not your site at all...

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered numerous times. I suggest searching `[Azure] 'load testing'` and start reading. You'll need to decide between installing a tool to a virtual machine or Cloud Service (Visual Studio Test, JMeter, etc.) and subscribing to a service (LoadStorm)... For the latter, if you're focused on maximum app load, you'll probably want to use a service that runs within Azure, and make sure they have load generators in the same data center as your system-under-test.

Announced at TechEd 2013, the Team Foundation Test Service will be available in Preview on June 26 (coincident with the //build conference). This will certainly give you load testing from Azure-based load generators. Read [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/03/introducing-cloud-based-load-testing-with-team-foundation-service.aspx) for more details.

Comment: More information on Visual Studio Cloud Load Test getting started - https://www.visualstudio.com/features/vso-cloud-load-testing-vs